# What are the requirements to build a city?

Tags: catan

In order to build a city you must have a settlement to upgrade, and enough resource for the upgrade.

However, are there any other requirements like having at least 3 settlements?

Comment: The two downvoters are welcome to have a voice in this comment section

Comment: if I had to guess why they downvoted you, i'd say it's because you asked an obvious question that is covered by the the rule book. Toon Krijthe was gracious enough to answer your question, but someone could have just as easily flagged your question.

Comment: @holaymolay, understood however when 6 people end up playing and 1 seems to claim a certain rule it is reassuring to verify in popular forums whether it's true or made-up house rule,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's only one other requirement: You need to have a spare city in stock.

To summarize, all the requirements are:

1. You need to have the required resources.
2. You need to have a settlement on the board.
3. You need to have a spare city in stock.

Comment: Also in my playgroup, you can't be one point from winning, otherwise you'll win, your wife will be upset, and you'll be sleeping on the couch. YMMV.

Comment: @corsiKa why would your playgroup not allow someone to win by upgrading a city?

Comment: @holaymolay Oh you're allowed. But then you win. And if you win, she doesn't win. And if she doesn't win, it's couchtown population you. Capiche?